# How to order by step by step field in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I'm using sql and i have a table that looks like:

```
Id   roomid  startBookingRoom      EndBookingRoom        startTime   
1     1     2010/10/10 15:00:00    2010/10/10 18:00:00  2019/04/29 15:00:00
2     2     2010/10/09 15:00:00    2010/10/09 18:00:00  2019/04/30 15:00:00
3     3     2010/10/08 15:00:00    2010/10/08 18:00:00  2019/04/31 15:00:00
3     4     2010/10/06 15:00:00    2010/10/68 18:00:00  2019/04/31 15:00:00
3     4     2010/10/06 14:00:00    2010/10/68 18:00:00  2019/04/31 15:00:00
```

I want order startTime Desc(2019/04/31 first and 2010/04/31 second). Then in startTime(2019/04/31 15:00:00) , I want order roomId Desc(4 first and 3 secord). Anh then in room id, i want order startBookingRoom ASC( 2010/10/06 14:00:00 first and  2010/10/06 15:00:00  second)

Step by step order look like: Order startTime by desc, if same startTime, order room Id desc, if same roomId then order startBookingRoom.

**startTime(desc) => roomId => startBookingRoom**

I write sql look like but it's not correct:

```
Select * from rooms when startTime >= '2019/04/25' order by
startTime,roomId,startBookingRoom
```

but it's not working.
How to order step by step startTime(desc) => roomId => startBookingRoom 
look like : Order startTime by desc, if same startTime, order room Id desc, if same roomId then order startBookingRoom. Thank you

Comment: MySQL and Postgres are completely different products!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default order by is ASC (ascending) so in your case add DESC (descending)

```
Select * from rooms where startTime >= '2019/04/25' 
order by startTime DESC, roomId DESC, startBookingRoom DESC
```